# Roslaunch error: Bad argument __name:=

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I have a ros node that runs without problem when it's called by rosrun, but dies without reason when called by a roslaunch:

```
NODES
  /
    CalibrateInt (tracking/calibrateInt)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[CalibrateInt-1]: started with pid [27132]
ERROR: 
  Bad argument __name:=CalibrateInt

[CalibrateInt-1] process has died [pid 27132, exit code 255, cmd /home/guillem/ros_workspace/Armed-turtlebot/tracking/bin/calibrateInt __name:=CalibrateInt __log:=/home/guillem/.ros/log/7c0acfb0-2f0e-11e2-948f-446d5719810b/CalibrateInt-1.log].
log file: /home/guillem/.ros/log/7c0acfb0-2f0e-11e2-948f-446d5719810b/CalibrateInt-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

launchfile:

```
<launch>
     <node pkg="tracking" type="calibrateInt" name="CalibrateInt"/>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48359/roslaunch-error:-bad-argument-__name:=/) by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess your node is using command line parameters but it is not ignoring additional, ros specific parameters.

While rosrun really just calls a binary and only passes the parameters you explicitly specify, roslaunch always adds the parameter `__name` to set the node name and maybe a few more. Topic remappings are also implemented using command line parameters. Make sure your node also accepts ros specific parameters or avoid command line parameters at all. Using the parameter server is a much better choice in most cases.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-11-15**:
Which is why usually all arguments are passed to ROS when [Initializing the roscpp Node](http://ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Initializing_the_roscpp_Node Initializing_the_roscpp_Node)

**Comment by [Jep](https://answers.ros.org/users/2367/jep/) on 2012-11-16**:
Thanks! you were right.
I'm using ROS parameters now instead.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-16**:
Great. But please read http://ros.org/wiki/Support Do **not** create answers for discussion, updates or comments. Instead, please either use the comment functionality or **edit** your original post.